# Local Notifications not opening the ViewController when application is not running in background

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uilocalnotification

I am working with local notifications, Whenever I set a local notification at particular time and when my app is in background, the local notifications pops up and when I click on them the delegate function is called

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

//Open your VC here
}
```

This works fine,

Now when after setting notifications for particular time, I kill the app from background, notifications pops up, when I click on them I want to open my VC,I tried it this way

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (locationNotification)
    {
         //Open VC
    }
}
```

But its not working,

Please help

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Does the code you have within your if statement get executed? How are you trying to open the VC? Remember that in the first case, there is already a UIWindow with a View hierarchy visible. In the second case you will first have to show the UIWindow and then add the VC to the hierarchy.

Comment: The code inside if statement is not executing because notification returned from UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey is nil @Iammert

Comment: And in your second case, is `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` not executed after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: NSLog("%@", launchOptions) Do you get notification in log?

Comment: @lammert no, its not getting executed